# Объект удалит сам себя

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

У меня есть следующая структура: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В правой стороне изображен класс А, который содержит свойство типа List; 
В левой стороне изображена схема визуальных компонент типа UserControl, в компоненте такого типа есть поле Field, это поле получает значение в конструкторе этого компонента.

Например класс А выглядит так:

```
    public class A
    {
        public List<T> Property1 {get; set;};                       
    }
```

Например класс UserControl выглядит так:

```
    public sealed class UserControl_ : UserControl
    {
        public T Field;

        public UserControl_ (T field)
        {
            Field = field;
        }            
    }
```

Пусть есть форма Form1 и там есть метод для создания UserControl(ов):

```
    public void CreateControl(list<T> list)
    {
        foreach(item in list)
        {
            Controls.Add(new UserControl_(item));
        }
    }
```

Управлять свойствами класса А, я могу через компонент PropertyGrid. Так вот что мне необходимо: когда я удаляю из свойства Property1 типа List элемент (например item 0), то нужно удалить визуальный контрол UserControl 1. Если у меня будет в Property1 10 элементов, то и UserControl(ов) будет 10. Каждый элемент Property1 содержится в контролах UserControl (связь один к одному)

Как быть?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper, PropertyGrid это контрол, позволяющий править атрибуты класса https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Так это WindowsForms...так сразу бы и написали